# jQuery and Bootstrap: Retain "active" after view navigation

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

How can I keep the selected button in a `Bootstrap` button group active after navigation?  Right now, the "active" class is removed from the selected button in the button group.  This is in a `MVC 5` app.

What I've tried is capturing the value (*.val()*...all button values are unique) in `localStorage` and using this value when the window is loaded (after navigation) to set the selected button to active.  I'm able to get the value, but having a difficult time retrieving it and getting the right button set to active (maybe there's a better way to do this?).

View (MVC):

```
<div class="form-group">
            <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
                <label class="btn btn-primary active">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-record"></span>
                    @Html.RadioButtonFor(i => i.Type, "Inbound", new {@id = "Inbound" }) Inbound
                </label>
                <label class="btn btn-primary">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-record"></span>
                    @Html.RadioButtonFor(i => i.Type, "InboundAuth", new { @id = "InboundAuth" }) Inbound Auth
                </label>
                <label class="btn btn-primary">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-record"></span>
                    @Html.RadioButtonFor(i => i.Type, "InboundRFS", new { @id = "InboundRFS" }) Inbound RFS
                </label>
                <label class="btn btn-primary">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-unchecked"></span>
                    @Html.RadioButtonFor(i => i.Type, "Outbound", new { @id = "Outbound" }) Outbound
                </label>
            </div>
 </div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $(".btn-group > .btn").click(function () {
            // This works
            localStorage.buttonName = $(this).children("input:first").val();
            alert(localStorage.buttonName);
        });
        // DOESN'T DO THE JOB
        // I'VE HARDCODED 'InboundAuth' JUST FOR TESTING PURPOSES
        $(window).load(function () {
           $('.btn-group > .btn[value="InboundAuth"]').addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is interested, here's what I did to make this work:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        // Save the button in localstorage and use it set the active class later on
        //
        $(".btn-group > .btn").click(function (event) {
            localStorage.buttonId = event.target.id;
        });

        // Set the active button based on the localstorage value
        //
        $(window).load(function () {
            var id = '#' + localStorage.Id;
            $('.btn-group').find(id).addClass('active');
        });

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

In MVC you could use routing as variable for such a cases.Based on my experience this is the best approach in that. Use

> location.pathname

and try something like:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('.btn-group > .btn').removeClass('active');
    $('.btn-group > .btn').find('a[href="' + location.pathname + '"]')
            .closest('.btn').addClass('active');
});
```

This works if you have "herf" properties on your "btn-group".

Comment: I don't have hrefs and it doesn't make sense to add it either.  I think I should be able to use value, name, id

Comment: Why you don't want to add it?

Comment: Why would I add and href where it's not needed or used?